# Kendo ui listbox select item after reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, listbox

I have a kendo listbox and want to select the item back after i reordedr it. I manage to reorder the items but i cannot select the item itself after reorder.
Anyone can help?

This is my code in reorder the item:

```
reorder: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;

            var dataItem = e.dataItems[0]
            var index = dataSource.indexOf(dataItem) + e.offset;
            dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            dataSource.insert(index, dataItem);
            var listBox = $("#configList").data("kendoListBox");

            //select the item  Not Work
            listBox.select(e.items);


        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of your reorder function:

```
e.sender.wrapper.find("[data-uid='"+UID+"']").addClass("k-state-selected");
```